# Why 'the' is used before the word 'problem' in the below context?

Tags: definite-article

> The problem related to poverty can't be overcome.

I have to ask that the word "problem", is an abstract noun, then, why definite article 'the' is used before it ?

Comment: The sentence is odd in that **problem** is in the singular, when there are multiple problems related to poverty.  However, you could say *The problem **of poverty** can't be overcome* as that establishes poverty itself as a problem.

Comment: Countable nouns except in titles need a, the. a or a plural or some determiner. You can't just say: Apple is good for you. [meaning a piece of that fruit]

Comment: the word problem is not an abstract noun.; poverty, is.

Comment: @TimR It probably makes more sense in context. Say for example, *"Childhood malnutrition is hard to tackle in [country]. Poverty and vitamin deficiencies are two main causes, and while vitamins can be added to popular foods, if people can't buy food, it may be moot.* The problem related to poverty can't be overcome. *It would require an overhaul of [country]'s economic system, which is beyond the scope of this committee."*

Comment: @wjandrea  I suppose we can imagine a context where "the problem" refers back to an earlier single specific problem  related to poverty which is the topic of discussion. Even so, "*the* problem related to poverty" still strikes me as odd way to refer back to the problem. I'd expect "*this* problem".

Answer (score 9):

There's no rule that says that abstract nouns don't have a definite determiner.

> The love I feel for you is special.

But if you leave the word indefinite: "Love is very important to me"

This is a specific and determined problem, and it is made definite by the phrase "related to poverty", and so the definite article "the" should be used.

Moreover, unlike "love", *problem* is a countable noun, so it can have an indefinite article:  "A problem that the world faces is the problem of poverty".

Your underlying misconception is to think that "abstract noun" is a grammatical category of noun, like "plural noun".  It isn't. It describes the meaning of certain words, not their grammar.

Comment: Actually, there is: Wealth can be a good thing. Love is eternal. Hate is not a good thing.

Comment: Of course, when something is specific, it takes a **the** determiner, as your examples show. When one makes a general statement about those terms, they do not. That's the "rule".

Comment: Of course it is semantic. That's the whole point.

Comment: Anyway, problem is not an abstract noun. And it is NOT a rule for any noun because you can't just say: Problem of poverty is x. You are obliged to say: The problem of poverty is X.

Comment: James, it is not the same rule for any noun: Countables need a determiner; love, hate and anger (abstracts) etc. in general statements do not, just like uncountables, which also do not necessarily take a determiner: coffee, tea and lemonade.

Comment: I doubt that "'abstract **noun**' [...] describes the meaning of certain **verbs**"... did you mean "words"?

Answer (score 3):

Using "the" before "problem" means we are talking about a specific problem. While it is evident that problem is related to poverty, we don't know exactly what the problem is.

Thus, such a sentence makes sense only if there was talk about it beforehand. Also, seeing as how "related to poverty" is a long string, I assume one would use it to distinguish it from some other problem, and/or bring it back to memory because it was mentioned some time ago. An example:

> There are two problems developing further space technology. One is the
> limited budget, a result of the country's money being distributed more
> towards reducing poverty. The other is limited technical expertise.
> Regarding the expertise, there has been some development to give more
> incentive for people to become researchers. The problem related to
> poverty can't be overcome.

Answer (score -2):

There’s no problem with *the problem*. Consider, for example

> **The problem** with internal-combustion engines is their tailpipe emissions: both pollutants and greenhouse gases.